# How to generate static html file in asp.net with C#?

Tags: c#, html

I need to generate static html files in asp.net with C#.
I know PHP should have the function to generate static html file, how to do the same thing with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following links:

[ASP.NET C# Properly Generating HTML for Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195306/asp-net-c-sharp-properly-generating-html-for-page)

[ASP.NET: dynamicly generating HTML, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409257/asp-net-dynamicly-generating-html-how-to)